# Recognize user returning to URL from same device

Tags: python, django, session, web

I'm new to web programming, so I guess my question would seem very stupid :)

I have simple website on Python/Django. There is some url, which users may open without any authentication.
I need to remember this user somehow and recognize him when he re-opens this url once again (not for a long time - say, for several hours).

By "same user" I mean "user uses same browser on same device".

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coookies are your answer. They will work for any URL for the same browser. assuming your user has agreed to use them.
An alternative would be to tag the links with parameters, but that is specific to the link and could be shared with others.

Comment: Got it, thanks! As @Barmar mentioned, Django has high-level anonymous sessions based on cookies. Thanks you both, guys! :)